# How to write a function that prints the highest number out of three numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a function that will return the highest number out of three numbers.

I tried it with this code:

```py
# The input will run until i reaches 2 (starts from 1)
# i will only get incremented when the input is valid (= is an integer) 
i = 1
while i < 2:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        y = int(input("Enter second number: "))
        z = int(input("Enter third number: "))
        i += 1
# when the input isn't valid (= is a string), the user must enter a valid value (integer)
    except ValueError:
        print("You entered a string. Try again.")


# Define the function
def max_of_three(x, y, z):
    if x > y and x > z or x == y > z or x == z > y:
        print (f"The highest number out of {x}, {y} and {z} is: ", x)
    if y > x and y > z or y == z > x:
        print (f"The highest number out of {x}, {y} and {z} is: ", y)
    if z > x and z > y:
        print (f"The highest number out of {x}, {y} and {z} is: ", z)
    if x == y == z:
        print ("All numbers are equal")


# Output function
max_of_three(x, y, z)
```

Fortunately, the code is working! But I wonder if there is any simplier or easier way to solve this problem.

Comment: `print(max([x, y, z]))`?

Comment: Does this homework come with a constraint that you can't use the `max` function?

Comment: The max solution is best, but 
you might have reduced the first if statement to 
`if x>= y and x >= z:`
similiar simplification for the second if statement.

You should also use `if ... elif ... elif ... else` to avoid retesting already known facts

Comment: so I'm new to python and didn't thought about the max function, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: @gelonida You can use comparison chaining instead: `if y <= x => z:`

Comment: @blhsing true, even shorter. didn't think about putting x in the middle

Comment: Perhaps you might rewrite your code to work with n entries  (n>2), store the values in a list and check with max. or if you're not allowed to use max implement it yourself.

I think your current version doesn't really handle the requirement of the first  comment `# i will only get incremented when the input is valid (= is an integer)`

This formulation is almost begging for a loop and try / except.

You might have to read about try / except to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use built-in [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) functions, like this:

```
def max_of_three(x, y, z):
    max_number = max(x,y,z)
    min_number = min(x,y,z)
    if max_number == min_number :
        print ("All numbers are equal")
    else:
        print (f"The highest number out of {x}, {y} and {z} is: ", max_number)
```